# How to get Spinner Selected Item in Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am making a currency converter with two spinners.  I want to make an "if" function using the values of the spinner's selected item like below.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (spinner1.getSelectedItem()=="Dollars" && spinner2.getSelectedItem()=="Euros") {
            convertDollarstoEuros();
        }
        if (spinner1.getSelectedItem()=="Euros" && spinner2.getSelectedItem()=="Euros") {
            convertEurostoEuros();
        }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "OnClickListener : " + 
                    "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                    "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

The problem is that the toast is showing, but the currencies aren't converting.  The toast part is working, but the spinner part isn't.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my LogCat:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Dollars") && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Euros")
...
```

getSelectedItem() returns an `Object` . [info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) . So you have to get the corresponding string first.
Then java compares strings using `equals()`.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working.  Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (spinner1.getSelectedItem()=="Dollars" && spinner2.getSelectedItem()=="Euros") {
```

You can't compare Strings like that. You have to use the `equals()` method to compare them. Use this:

```
if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Dollars") && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Euros")) {}
```

Comment: @user2489834 Yes, add the LogCat to your question.

Comment: I do not know how to do that, so should I upload my whole source code?

Comment: @user2489834 you can copy-paste it. (I only need the exception. It looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/oRqfTrm.png )

Comment: At least paste us the name of the exception (first 2 or 3 lines).

Comment: How do you do that?  I searched on Google (I have a Windows computer) but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What are you using? Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: Go to Window > Show View > Other > Android > Logcat.

Comment: I editted my answer.  You can now find the url of the logcat image.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you called the id correctly or not? When I was working when improper id was called this exception used to arise. For eg In TextView, findViewById(R.id.textView1) but in xml file we may have set it to textView2.