# Spinner inandroid studio

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have 2 spinners and 1 edit text. How to get selected spinner item. I need to know witch ones are selected, so I could show conversion resoult in other activity.

First spinner have 2 items ( Celsius and Fahrenheit) second also. How to call one of 2 methods depending on spinner item select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spinner Selected Item in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129021/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference for your spinners. Extract the selected value of the spinners like this:

```
String spinnerValue = String.valueOf(spinnerReference.getSelectedItem());
```

Considering that spinnerValue can contain either "Farenheit" or "Celsisus", you can use a switch block to call the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check currently selected item in the spinner you should have an instance of it. If you don't make sure you assign an id (for example "unitSpinner") to it in the layout file and then in the Activity's onCreate method call `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.<idYouAssigned>)`. Then you can call `spinner.getSelectedItem()` which will return either "Celsuius" or "Fahrenheit" depending on which one the user selected.